# C++ substr and find_first_of

Tags: c, strtok

I want to change my question.

please let me know what's happening;

```
type is "CHAR(10)"

size = type.substr(type.find_first_of("("), type.find_first_of(")"));
cout << "SIZE : " << size << endl;
cout << "SIZE : " << size.substr(1, (size.length())-1) << endl;

SIZE : (10)
SIZE : 10)
```

I only need to 10. I can not do that.

Comment: what do you mean by not working well..show us your code and what problems you are facing with it.

Comment: not working well?  as in it works ok, but not great?

Comment: how can I post my code here? -,- not easy.

Comment: @newmkka: Edit your question, paste the code, select it and press  CTRL+K to format it. Thats all.

Comment: Wait, is this C or C++?  That call to `push_back` makes me suspicious.

Comment: Does look like C++, with the comment about "save to vector", but could be valid C.  The most obvious issue is upper vs lower case; and then there's the fact that `strtok` itself is almost always the wrong way to parse anything other than whitespace-separated words.

Comment: Erm, if you get 1 character too much using `size.substr(1, (size.length())-1)` , then why not use `size.substr(1, (size.length())-2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function substr in std::string has two arguments
first argument is index of begining and the second argument is length of substring you need

```
string type = "CHAR(10)";

int k1,k2;
size = type.substr(k1=type.find_first_of("("), k2=type.find_first_of(")"));
cout<<"index="<< k1<<" len=" << k2 << endl;
cout << "SIZE : " << size << endl;
cout << "SIZE : " << size.substr(1, (size.length())-1) << endl;

index1=4 len=7
SIZE : (10)
SIZE : 10)
```

this is simple to find that size is substring of type from index 4 to 10 and because the size of type is 8 , your code print until the last character of your string

solution is:

```
k1= type.find_first_of("(");
k2=type.find_first_of(")");
k2-=k1;//now it's the length of size
size = type.substr(k1,k2);
```

Comment: thanks,
I made this style
int i, j = 0;
    i = type.find_first_of("(") + 1;
    j = type.find_first_of(")") - i;